# UML use case diagram server as system actor and which kind of use cases

Tags: mobile, uml, requirements, use-case

I´m creating an use case diagram based on the following scenario:

There is a mobile application which passes data to an webserver/database. The webserver on the other hand sends data to the mobile application.

So i have two questions:

- Data send to the application is individual data only for this smartphone/user. So does it make sense to show server/database as an external system actor which gets connected with the specific use cases?
- Are use cases (for the mobile app) like "showing information about something" oder "refresh data" necessary? Because i think they are not necessary for the business logic. What do you think?

Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Data send to the application is individual data only for this
>   smartphone/user. So does it make sense to show server/database as an
>   external system actor which gets connected with the specific use
>   cases?

Only if the server/database is *really an external system*, to which your system communicates. If not, then it cannot be an actor, and you should mandatory make an additional UML modelling to clarify the overall system structure (component diagram + sequences).

The fact that the data is individual has nothing to do with this decision. :)

> Are use cases (for the mobile app) like "showing information about
>   something" oder "refresh data" necessary? Because i think they are not
>   necessary for the business logic. What do you think?

If you are building this mobile app, and *these are the requirements to implement*, than you should definitelly capture them as use cases.

What do you mean by "they are not necessary for the business logic"?

What is scope of your system in the first place? (mobile app, mobile app + server/database or something else)?

**UPDATE (after clearing up the system scope)**

> We are building the mobile app AND the database. So we are not just
>   getting data from there and send data. We´re modelling the whole
>   system

The scope is now clear - databese/server cannot be an actor, as it is part of the scope. The only actor I see is the mobile app user.

> when just placing the user beeing an actor and the app beeing the
>   system i don´t know how to describe the use case, because i think i
>   have to mention in the uce case description that data was send to
>   server, etc...

You do not have to put everything to the use case description, I will come back to this shortly.

> For example: one use case is about taking a picture and send this to
>   the server- –

So, what's the problem with this UC? The actor is the mobile app user and the use case is "Upload picture" (it can optionally include taking the picture).

I think you are confused with a mix of several concerns that you try to put all in use case model, and that is not possible.

So, I recommend you to separate the cpncerns (aspects of your system) making the following diagrams:

1. business level: an **activity diagram** showing the overall usage/business workflow of the app
2. a **use case model** to capture the reqs

*Be sure to make this model simple and from the Actor perspective. Just identify a small set of meaningful interactions the Actor can perform (not to low level).
For example: "Upload photo", "Refresh data" might be some solid UCs*

1. (optional) **conceptual/data model** (to clear up the relevant data structures)
2. system structure via **component/deployment diagram** (here you clearly have at least 3 components: mobile app, WEB server (or whatever receives the requests from the mobile app) and the database
3. **communication mechanisms** - sequence diagram(s) using components

And now you need some "glue" to relate the different concepts - for each use case make a sequence(s) that show how it works, using the elements from the component diagram (+ actor of couurse).

The point is to "open up" the use cases and show their internal implementation in terms of the system structure elements.

Comment: hi aleks, thanks for your comments. What do you mean with an external system? A system which not belongs to our architecture? Our architecture is the following: user could download the app. Login on the app is only possible when there was a registration on the web plattform before. After that user could "interact" with the database. Meaning send data to database and receive data from the database.

Comment: The question is actually if this database/server is a black-box in this context (you just communicate with it) or you also develop the database and these queries. I assume you are modelling the mobile app, please correct me if I'm wrong. Use cases are all about the scope of the system, so it is fundamental to make it clear.

Comment: We are building the mobile app AND the database. So we are not just getting data from there and send data. We´re modelling the whole system. So the reason why i´m unsure about this is the follwing fact: when just placing the user beeing an actor and the app beeing the system i don´t know how to describe the use case, because i think i have to mention in the uce case description that data was send to server, etc... For example: one use case is about taking a picture and send this to the server-

Comment: I will now update my original answer with further ideas.

Comment: Aleks, clearly formulated and easy to understand! I will accept this as answer. Thank your very much for your time!

Comment: Cool. Please don'r hesitate to ask again or just check your work.